# Does Number of cores affect execution time

Tags: multiprocessor

Say I have written a program that takes 30 seconds to execute on a dual core processor. What time it would take on a 16 core processor? same or differs

Two cases: 
One- the program is written with multiple cores in mind.
Two- program is written irrespective of no of cores.

Comment: The question is too vague to answer. It's kind like "I have some stuff to move, will it get there faster in a sports car or a truck?" It depends how much stuff, how far you're going, how big the biggest thing is, and so on.

Comment: hi david., vague? I really dint get whats vague in it. (my question was in comparison between executing same code in dual and more than 2 cores and execution time difference. Thank you.)

Comment: You don't tell us anything about what the code does or how it does it. And what does it mean for a program to be written "irrespective of no of cores"? Does that mean it's single-threaded? Are we to assume the work done is purely CPU bound? And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Viewed in isolation, then unless you have explicitly written multithreaded code, the runtime should be the same.
<sup>1</sup>  Of course, it might be faster if you have other applications running simultaneously, because they can now run on the other cores.

If you have written multithreaded code, then the speedup you see will be based on all sorts of factors (memory bandwidth, IO bandwidth, memory access patterns, cache coherency, synchronisation, etc.), as well as [*Amdahl's law*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law).  It will always be some number less than *N* (where *N* is the number of cores).

---

<sub>1. Assuming we're talking about a conventional platform.</sub>

Comment: Thanks v much Oli Charlesworth., :)